# Responsive vertical align for three equal boxes with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and would like to have three boxes of the same height align vertically.
[image]

Here you can see those three blocks, however I need them to be of equal height that will occupy maximum space. I can manually add some padding so it looks like that: [image]

However when the block becomes smaller (bootstrap's grid) it breaks.
[image]

Any ideas?
Here's CSS code I'm using and HTML layout.

```css
.caption {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0!important;
}
.caption-info{
 width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 9px;
}
.caption-flag:hover{
 background: rgba(235, 75, 75, 1);
 transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
.caption-flag{
 cursor: help!important;
 transition: background 0.2s ease;
 position: absolute;
    background: rgba(235, 75, 75, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.caption-info h4 { margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
.caption-prices{
 width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.caption-prices h4{
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.caption-square, .caption-cost, .caption-total{
 box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding-left: 0!important;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 padding: 5.5px;
}
.caption-square{
 background: green;
}
.caption-cost{
 background: orange;
}
.caption-total{
 background: red;
}
.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="caption-info">
          <h4><a href="#">Product Title</a></h4>
          <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="caption-prices">
          <div class="caption-square">
            площадь
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="caption-cost">
            цена за м<sup>2</sup>
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="caption-total">
            стоимость
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this rule

```
.caption-square, .caption-cost, .caption-total{
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding-left: 0!important;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    padding: 5.5px;
    height: 33%;                   /* added */
    box-sizing: border-box;        /* added */
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.caption {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0!important;
}
.caption-info{
 width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 9px;
}
.caption-flag:hover{
 background: rgba(235, 75, 75, 1);
 transition: background 0.2s ease;
}
.caption-flag{
 cursor: help!important;
 transition: background 0.2s ease;
 position: absolute;
    background: rgba(235, 75, 75, 0.75);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.caption-info h4 { margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;}
.caption-prices{
 width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.caption-prices h4{
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.caption-square, .caption-cost, .caption-total{
 box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding-left: 0!important;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 padding: 5.5px;
    height: 33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.caption-square{
 background: green;
}
.caption-cost{
 background: orange;
}
.caption-total{
 background: red;
}
.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
        <div class="caption-info">
          <h4><a href="#">Product Title</a></h4>
          <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="caption-prices">
          <div class="caption-square">
            площадь
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="caption-cost">
            цена за м<sup>2</sup>
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="caption-total">
            стоимость
            <h4>$24.99</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```